# Export multiple lists in table form to the same file

Tags: export

I have a list, call it mylist, made of many sublists that are just points from a plot and I would like to export that to a single file. Let's say I have, for example, something like this

```
mylist1={{1,2},{3,4}};
mylist2={{5,6},{7,8}};
mylist={mylist1,mylist2};
```

I need an output file like

```
1 2
3 4

5 6
7 8
```

(notice the empty line between the two sublists). If I do

```
Export["myfile.txt", mylist1, "Table"]
```

I obtain a file with

```
1 2
3 4
```

which is ok for a single sublist, but I don't know what to do in order to export all the sublists to the same file separated by an empty line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the matrices into a single matrix, and then export:

```
combined = Join[mylist1, {{}}, mylist2];

ExportString[combined, "Table"]
```

> ```
> 1   2
> 3   4
>
> 5   6
> 7   8
> ```

If you have many lists, you can use [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle) and [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate) to join the lists together:

```
ExportString[Catenate @ Riffle[mylist, {{{}}}], "Table"]
```

> ```
> 1   2
> 3   4
>
> 5   6
> 7   8
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I did use your second suggestion having multiple sublists with `Export["myfile.txt",ExportString[Catenate@Riffle[mylist, {{{}}}], "Table"]]`